# Fix malparsed XML file with Notepadd++

Tags: xml, notepad++

Got a malparsed XML file that is displaying as a long single line.   Trying to use Notepadd++  to fix this .

Using find `(><)`  and replacing with `\r\n\1`  which gets be something like this

```
><home>new york</home
><number>8234</number
><id>0409</id
```

I would like to get it to

```
<home>new york</home>
<number>8234</number>
<id>0409</id
```

Can't figure out how to do this.  Can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Is this how the text in your file is?

```
<home>new york</home><number>8234</number><id>0409</id>
```

You just have to ***Find*** `><` and ***Replace*** it with `>\n<`, while setting the ***Search Mode*** to `Extended`.

[image]